# Live-Action Japanese movie from the early 90s

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I'm looking for a film from the early 90s or late 80s that has a similar look to the James Cameron Aliens film; it's in Japanese. There is a tank, a kid with a suit that has pressure points that make beat-box like noises when pressed, and a man/police(?) who is probably the main character. I think there is a woman too... I seem to remember the film has a very dark look to it with a lot of mist, most likely to help disguise the use of miniatures and forced perspective... THANKS!

Oh, BTW, I seem to remember seeing this (?) film around the time of the live action Guyver films...

Comment: Was there animation mixed in with the live-action?

Comment: Oh man, that's a tough one... I really doubt it, but again, we're going on MY memory from 2 decades ago LOL. I think it was straight-up live action based on anime. I seem to remember a strong resemblance with Aliens production design... and what I'm particularly interested in referencing is the kid's suit that makes beat-box noises when pressing the various pads located on the chest, arms and legs... that's why I'm trying to remember the title of the film. It's tremendously obscure, I've searched IMDb and various lists online... I can find Guyver no problem, but not this film... It was fairly

Comment: @AnonJoe If you want your two accounts merged, go here and request it: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 5):

Sorry guys, I found the answer finally! [Gunhed](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097410/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)! Glory be the internet!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  On what do you base that answer ?  You have any links to reference ?  Expectation on the site is that answers are supported by some type of referencing material and not just a statement of 'this is the answer'.

Comment: @Stan They're probably the same person, and he found it somewhere and recognized it.

Comment: @Tacroy - even if it's the same person, still needs to provide some kind of basis for saying 'this is it' if he wants to post it as an answer.  If he found something on the WEB, a link to site is a pretty easy reference to provide.

Comment: @Stan if it's his question, does he need to provide the source to his own answer?

Comment: @Stan Yes, a link to a site is a pretty easy reference to provide.  Good thing you don't need to be the author of a post to provide an edit.  You even have enough reputation to do it without waiting for approval ;)

Comment: @Beofett - Guess I was of the opinion that answerer should have provided their own source.  I have no idea what particular reference he uncovered.  Personally, I think you should now be getting the credit for the upvotes.

Comment: @Monty129 - That's my opinion, see my comment to Beofett.  Others may disagree.

Comment: @Stan The OP is new, and unregistered. From their standpoint, all they may be interested in is finding the title that's nagging at their memory. I think we should count it a "win" that they even came back to share with us that they found what they were looking for.  I'd happily sacrifice the reputation if it resulted in more motivation for a new user to come back and participate in the future.

Comment: +1 @Beofett - You make an excellent point, thanks for reining me in.  BTW - I was being a bit facetious on the upvote credit :)

Comment: @Stan no worries, and thanks for taking it in the spirit I intended it: no criticism intended towards you, but rather a reminder that the community is more welcoming to new users if those of us familiar with the platform give them a little leeway :)